# What is your process for migrating questions?

Tags: discussion, support

Came across [How to check whether a word is abbreviated or not using Python?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13838/how-to-check-whether-a-word-is-abbreviated-or-not-using-python) this question you migrated to Open Data this morning.
This is not an Open Data question; it may not be a Data Science question, but its certainly not an Open Data question. I've noticed a few of these over time. Feels like if there is no immediate answer, they just get dumped into OD.

What is the process for kicking questions over to other sites?
If this question is not y'alls, then it most certainly is one of the programming language subs or even simply SO.

I'm inclined to send this right back to you and let you deal with it, but I'm not sure if that is the right move and/or how to do that.

Any thoughts here are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I agree.  It does not appear to me that this should have been migrated anywhere.  It looks like it garnered several off-topic close votes before one of our former moderators decided to migrate it.  We do not have a standard close reason for migrating, although it looks like we do migrate 2-3 questions a month in your direction.

And as to you sending it back, that would seem quite a reasonable to me.  My understanding is that closing the question will cause the migration to be rejected.

FYI: In case you have not run across it, on the moderator dashboard there is a tab to show migration history.

Comment: thanks! that helps/clears things up for me.